# Google Earth Engine Python API Warning

Tags: warnings, google-api-python-client, google-earth-engine

Yesterday, I created a script to get Sentinel-1 images for a specific region and the code ran as expected. Today, running the same code with no changes I get the following warning:

WARNING:googleapiclient.http:Sleeping 0.91 seconds before retry 1 of 5 for request: POST https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/value:compute?prettyPrint=false&alt=json, after 500

I am wondering if this is a quota issue? Or some other issue?

Comment: Same issue here. Also noticed EECU usage, task time and fails spiking after the message. [EECU-seconds increased 100-fold for the same tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y6uO.png)
vs. [an identical task in principle before the warning popped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUESW.png)